# Modeling static Coulomb friction in a multibody system

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, friction, coulombs-law

I have a multibody system with Coulomb friction:

[image]

I'm able to write horizontal linear momentum conservation equations:

1. $m_1 \ddot{x}_1 = F_1 - F_{f12}$
2. $m_2 \ddot{x}_2 = F_2 + F_{f12} - F_{f23}$
3. $m_3 \ddot{x}_3 = F_3 + F_{f23} - F_{f34}$
4. $m_4 \ddot{x}_4 = F_4 + F_{f34}$

And I'm also able to calculate $F_{f12}$ and $F_{f34}$ as below:

1. $F_{f12}=\left\{\begin{matrix}
     if \, \dot{x_1}=\dot{x_2} \, and \, \left| F_1-m_1 \ddot{x}_1 \right|<\mu_s F_{n12} \, then &  F_1-m_1 \ddot{x}_1 \\
     else &  \mu_k F_{n12}sgn\left(\dot{x_1}-\dot{x_2}\right)
    \end{matrix}\right.$
2. $F_{f34}=\left\{\begin{matrix}
     if \, \dot{x_3}=\dot{x_4} \, and \, \left| F_4+m_4 \ddot{x}_4 \right|<\mu_s F_{n34} \, then &  -F_4-m_4 \ddot{x}_4 \\
     else &  \mu_k F_{n12}sgn\left(\dot{x_4}-\dot{x_3}\right)
    \end{matrix}\right.$

Here the static friction opposes any external force up to the maximum static friction.

I have two issues:

1. when the conditions for static friction $\dot{x_i}=\dot{x_j} \, and \, \left| F_i-m_i \ddot{x}_i \right|<\mu_s F_{nij}$ are valid the equation becomes the exact same equation as the linear momenta, and I end up with less equations than my unknowns.
2. I'm not able to write $F_{f23}$ because the opposing forces here include other static frictions and we end up with two different equations!

For example if we write $F_{f23}$ based on mass 3:

$F_{f23}=\left\{\begin{matrix}
  if \, \dot{x_2}=\dot{x_3} \, and \, \left|  F_{f34} -F_3 -m_3 \ddot{x}_3\right|<\mu_s F_{n23} \, then &  F_{f34} -F_3 -m_3 \ddot{x}_3   \\
  else &  \mu_k F_{n23}sgn\left(\dot{x_2}-\dot{x_3}\right)
 \end{matrix}\right.$

But if we write $F_{f23}$ based on mass 2 we get:

$F_{f23}=\left\{\begin{matrix}
  if \, \dot{x_2}=\dot{x_3} \, and \, \left| F_2 + F_{f12}-m_2 \ddot{x}_2\right|<\mu_s F_{n23} \, then &  F_2 + F_{f12} -m_2 \ddot{x}_2  \\
  else &  \mu_k F_{n23}sgn\left(\dot{x_2}-\dot{x_3}\right)
 \end{matrix}\right.$

And the equality of $F_2 + F_{f12}=F_{f34}-F_3$ is not necessarily valid.

I would appreciate if you could help me know

1. if my math is correct so far?
2. how to write  $F_{f23}$?

Comment: The true equations for the upper and the lower side must naturally be true at the same time. So if they disagree, then they aren't correct and it must be another one of the possible cases.

Comment: @Steeven do not follow, would you please elaborate?

Comment: I don't see any immediate errors in the math, so assuming everything holds, you now have yourself a nice equality to check up with to know which situation you have. *If* the forces happen to fit, so that the final equality $$F_2+F_{f12}=F_{f34}-F_3$$is true, then you know that the first cases of both $F_{f23}$'s are true. If they do not, then the first cases can't both be true (only one of them or maybe none of them).

Comment: @Steeven Well, I already know the equality does not hold. this is a simplified version of my actual model. I have been trying to model this in SIMULINK without success, I have had some progress in OpenModelica thanks to the non-causal nature of the solver, though. this is the only challenge I need to overcome.

Comment: I don't think you set up the form of $F_{f12}$ or $F_{f34}$ correctly. The way they're currently set up, neither $m_1$ nor $m_4$ can accelerate at all unless they're sliding. But if $m_2$ is accelerating, then $m_1$ can accelerate at the same rate without having $F_{f12}=F_1$.

Comment: @JohnathanGross you are absolutely right and I had already thought about this. the correct way actually is :
$F_{f12}=\left\{\begin{matrix}
  if \, \dot{x_1}=\dot{x_2} \, and \, \left| m_1\ddot{x_1}- F_1 \right|<\mu_s F_{n12} \, then &  F_1- m_1\ddot{x_1} \\
  else &  \mu_k F_{n12}sgn\left(\dot{x_1}-\dot{x_2}\right)
 \end{matrix}\right.$ but the issue is the static friction yields the same equation as the linear momenta conservation and I end up with less equations than the unknowns! I don't know how to solve this either!

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange, and thank you so much for typing up your math with mathjax!

Comment: @heather I'm the one who should be thankful for being provided with this feature. I wish we had this in all other SO forums.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no other way to determine static friction except as whatever happens to balance Newton's 2nd Law.

Comment: @JohnathanGross I will add this to the question. but I'm afraid it makes it more complicated. thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Keep in mind this applies to $F_{f23}$ as well. $F_{f23}=F_2+F_{f12}-m_2\ddot{x_2}=F_{f34}-F_3+m_3\ddot{x_3}$.

Comment: There is some hope though. The condition $\dot{x_1}=\dot{x_2}$ forces $\ddot{x_1}=\ddot{x_2}$. This simplifies your coupled second order equations into coupled first order equations.

Comment: @JohnathanGross I edited the post, fixing this mistake, but for your latest comment: not really. the fact that $\dot{x_i}=\dot{x_j}$ in an instance does not mean $\ddot{x_i}=\ddot{x_j}$ at that moment!

Comment: I Think I have solved the issue. would you guys please take a look at my answer and see if it is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**New:**

Since posting this question I was able to rewrite the equations in a more elegant way. Actually regardless of being a multibody problem friction between each individual bodies is the same and other frictional forces are just forces! Static friction tries to keep two bodies as one as far as it can. it means for a two body problem:

[image]

1. $m_1 \ddot{x}_1 = F_1 - F_{f12}$
2. $m_2 \ddot{x}_2 = F_2 + F_{f12}$
3. $\ddot{x}_1=\ddot{x}_2$
4. $\implies \, F_{s12}=\frac{m_2 F_1-m_1F_2}{m_1+m_2}$

considering that the maximum static friction is $F_{s_{max}12}=\mu_s F_{n12}$

$\implies F_{f12}=\left\{\begin{matrix}
  if \, \dot{x_1}=\dot{x_2} \, and \, \left| F_{s12} \right|<F_{s_{max}12} \,\, then &  F_{s12} \\
  else &  \mu_k F_{n12}sgn\left(\dot{x_1}-\dot{x_2}\right)
 \end{matrix}\right.$

I have also implemented this in Modelica language and SIMULINK. you may see them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47224549/openmodelica-solver-reaches-maximal-number-of-iteration-but-not-able-to-find-roo) and [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/28227/moedlica-and-simulink-yield-completely-different-results)

**Old:**

I think I have figured the issue out. Thanks to the questions asked in the comments I had to rewrite some of the equations and then the main misunderstanding was revealed to me. Actually when the conditions for static frictions hold the two parts act as one. we can write the 3 frictions as below:

1. If $\dot{x_1}=\dot{x_2}$ and $\left| F_1-m_1 \ddot{x}_1 \right|<\mu_s F_{n12}$ and $\left| m_2 \ddot{x}_2-F_2+F_{f23} \right|<\mu_s F_{n12}$ then $\ddot{x}_1=\ddot{x}_2$ , else $F_{f12}=\mu_k F_{n12}sgn\left(\dot{x_1}-\dot{x_2}\right)$
2. If $\dot{x_3}=\dot{x_4}$ and $\left| F_4-m_4 \ddot{x}_4 \right|<\mu_s F_{n34}$ and $\left|  F_3 + F_{f23}-m_3 \ddot{x}_3 \right|<\mu_s F_{n34}$ then $\ddot{x}_3=\ddot{x}_4$ , else $F_{f34}=\mu_k F_{n34}sgn\left(\dot{x_4}-\dot{x_3}\right)$
3. If $\dot{x_2}=\dot{x_3}$ and $ \left| F_2 + F_{f12}-m_2 \ddot{x}_2\right|<\mu_s F_{n23} $ and $ \left|  F_{f34} -F_3 -m_3 \ddot{x}_3\right|<\mu_s F_{n23} $ then $\ddot{x}_3=\ddot{x}_2$ , 
   else $F_{f23}=\mu_k F_{n23}sgn\left(\dot{x_2}-\dot{x_3}\right)$